# Buffered read with Linux RS232 serial driver

Tags: linux, serial-port, driver

I am trying to read the serial port once in 10 bytes at 1200 Baud. However I observed that the drivers buffers some data(in my case 96 bytes) initially before read returning 10 bytes. Due to this buffering I am unable to process the data in real time...What could be the reason and what needs to be changed in my code or in the kernel serial driver to get 10 bytes each?. Incoming data flow is continuous at 1200 Baud.

## My Code:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/signal.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/serial.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <time.h>
#define BAUDRATE B1200
#define PACKET_SIZE 10
#define RXDEVICE_NAME "/dev/ttyM0"
#define CHAR_TIMEOUT 5 /*0.5sec timeout period*/
static void write2filerd(unsigned char *recvdata, time_t recvtime, int size,
        FILE *fp);
static void TimeToAsciird(time_t timeToConvert, char* buffer);

int main(void) {
    struct termios AP_term;
    int Inp_port = 0;
    time_t recvtime = 0;
    FILE *fptr;
    char textLine[256];
    unsigned char buf[100];
    unsigned int bytes = 0;
    int rd = 0;

    if ((fptr = fopen("/tmp/read.log", "w+")) < 0) {
        perror(" file open failed read ");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((Inp_port = open(RXDEVICE_NAME, O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY)) < 0) {
        perror("FAILED TO Open Port \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /*exit*/
    }
    bzero(&AP_term, sizeof(AP_term));
    tcsetattr(Inp_port, TCSANOW, &AP_term);

    AP_term.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    AP_term.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    AP_term.c_lflag = 0;
    AP_term.c_oflag = 0;
    AP_term.c_cc[VMIN] = 10;/*10 BYTES LENGTH*/
    AP_term.c_cc[VTIME] = CHAR_TIMEOUT;

    tcflush(Inp_port, TCIOFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(Inp_port, TCSANOW, &AP_term);
    bzero(&buf, sizeof(buf));

    tcflush(Inp_port, TCIOFLUSH);
    time(&recvtime);
    fprintf(fptr, "Start at ");
    fflush(fptr);
    TimeToAsciird(recvtime, textLine);
    strcat(textLine, "\n");
    fwrite(textLine, sizeof(char), strlen(textLine), fptr);
    fflush(fptr);

    ioctl(Inp_port, TIOCINQ, &bytes);
    fprintf(fptr, "Before bytes avail %d \n", bytes);
    fflush(fptr);
    while (1) {
        rd = read(Inp_port, buf, PACKET_SIZE);
        if (rd <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Read failure with %d: %s ", rd, strerror(errno));
            break;
        }
        ioctl(Inp_port, TIOCINQ, &bytes);
        time(&recvtime);
        write2filerd(buf, recvtime, rd, fptr);
        fprintf(fptr, "::bytes remaining %d \n", bytes);
        fflush(fptr);

    }
    time(&recvtime);
    fprintf(fptr, "End at ");
    fflush(fptr);
    TimeToAsciird(recvtime, textLine);
    strcat(textLine, "\n");
    fwrite(textLine, sizeof(char), strlen(textLine), fptr);
    fflush(fptr);
    fprintf(fptr, "END PROGRAM\n");
    fclose(fptr);
    close(Inp_port);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
}

static void write2filerd(unsigned char *recvdata, time_t recvtime, int size,
        FILE *fp) {

    unsigned char *buf = recvdata;

    char textLine[256];
    char *msg = malloc(80);
    char s[5];
    int i;

    *msg = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sprintf(s, "%02X ", buf[i]);
        strcat(msg, s);
    }
    TimeToAsciird(recvtime, textLine);
    strcat(textLine, " ");
    strcat(textLine, msg);
    strcat(textLine, " ");
    fwrite(textLine, sizeof(char), strlen(textLine), fp);
    fflush(fp);
    free(msg);

}
static void TimeToAsciird(time_t timeToConvert, char* buffer) {
    struct tm* timeStruct;

    timeStruct = localtime(&timeToConvert);

    sprintf(buffer, "%.2d:%.2d:%.2d %.2d/%.2d/%.2d", timeStruct->tm_hour,
            timeStruct->tm_min, timeStruct->tm_sec, timeStruct->tm_mday,
            timeStruct->tm_mon + 1, timeStruct->tm_year % 100);
}
```

The output from the above program:

```
Start at 21:40:59 14/08/15 
Before bytes avail 0 
21:41:03 14/08/15 06 07 00 00 12 FD A5 0B 67 9C ::bytes remaining 86 
21:41:03 14/08/15 06 07 00 01 12 FD A5 0B 67 9C ::bytes remaining 76 
21:41:03 14/08/15 06 07 00 02 12 FD A5 0B 67 9C ::bytes remaining 66 
21:41:03 14/08/15 06 07 00 03 12 FD A5 0B 67 9C ::bytes remaining 56 
21:41:03 14/08/15 06 07 00 04 12 FD A5 0B 67 9C ::bytes remaining 46 
21:41:03 14/08/15 06 07 00 05 12 FD A5 0B 67 9C ::bytes remaining 36
```

Comment: The output of the above program: Start at 21:40:59 14/08/15
Before bytes avail 0 
21:41:03 14/08/15 06 07 00 00 12 FD A5 0B 67 9C  ::bytes remaining 86 
21:41:03 14/08/15 06 07 00 01 12 FD A5 0B 67 9C  ::bytes remaining 76 
21:41:03 14/08/15 06 07 00 02 12 FD A5 0B 67 9C  ::bytes remaining 66 
21:41:03 14/08/15 06 07 00 03 12 FD A5 0B 67 9C  ::bytes remaining 56 
21:41:03 14/08/15 06 07 00 04 12 FD A5 0B 67 9C  ::bytes remaining 46 
21:41:03 14/08/15 06 07 00 05 12 FD A5 0B 67 9C  ::bytes remaining 36

Comment: shouldn't the first `tcsetattr` actually be a `tcgetattr` ? BTW the `strcat(msg, s);` is strange, since s[] is uninitialised.

Comment: tctsetattr is to clear initially. yes ;s' not initialized but working. This is only a sample code. Any idea about why the buffered read. I need to read in real time-10 bytes at a time

Comment: It is working by coincidence. For the reading part, I would use select() or poll(), adding each incoming char to a buffer, and using that buffer once the count reaches 10. Also keep in mind that read() can return -1/EINTR, which is *not* an error condition.

Comment: Tried with Select and Read as well. Buffered read is not solved. I need to receive as the data comes in real time. But I observe driver first buffers 96 bytes before read return. I also tried one character read. Still the drivers buffers before read returning...

Comment: Also, I would explicitely set the tty to non-canonical mode (I guess that is your intention) First do tcgetattr(), then mask off+mask on the appropiate bits.

Comment: *"tctsetattr is to clear initially"* -- That's simply bad coding practice! See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237) and
[Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html).  *" I also tried one character read."* -- Please clarify exactly what you did (e.g. show code not a description), as there is more than one way to do this.

Comment: Based on the program's output, the data buffering does not look like non-canonical mode, which I would expect to see a more random "remaining bytes" value. Instead it looks a lot like a canonical read, i.e. the "buffering" is controlled by the occurrence of a "line delimiter" character. **What does the actual data that is being read look like?** What is the 96th byte? And the 86th after that? And the 76th after that? And the 66th after that? And the 56th after that? And the 46th after that? Are they all the same value?

Comment: This is non-canonical read as the flag ICANON is made as zero. If we set ICANON flag read will not return till a delimiter is received. I am 200% sure it is non-canonical read. Seems like my kernel serial driver has a buffer threshold of 96 bytes. I need to know how to change the buffer threshold from the application. Anyone knows which driver source file look at for modifying the buffer threshold. I tried the low latency option in the tty driver source file without success. Seems like I need to locate the right ioctl option or the right driver source file.

Comment: Wildplasser and sawdust: Thanks for your effort. This issue is resolved now. Our driver vendor pointed me to the receive buffer water mark in the driver which was set to 96. It works as we expected after the modification